# How to lock a shared object before serialization in Asp.net core SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

For example, if I have a `static` `List<int>` object that is manipulated by multi thread, it is not safe to enumerate it without locking it first. When I return the list from a hub method or send it to client, SignalR will internally serialize it without locking it.

In a asp.net core ApiController method I can fully custom serialize it first:

```cs
static List<int> list;
object Get()
{
    string s;
    lock(list)
    {
         s = JsonConvert.Serialize(list);
    }
    return new ContentResult(){ Content = s, ContentType = "application/json"};
}
```

It is not perfect but works.

I have some solutions on it:

1. Clone the object, before pass it to SignalR.

   Disadvantage: Clone is expensive. And deep clone needs more code.
2. Use Newtonsoft json's [callback](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) and [error handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm).
   For example:

```cs
//the shared object that will return from a hub method
class SomeObject
{
    public List<int> list;

    [OnSerializing]
    internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(this);
    }
    [OnSerialized]
    internal void OnSerializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Monitor.Leave(this);
    }
    [OnError]
    internal void OnError(StreamingContext context, ErrorContext errorContext)
    {
        Monitor.Leave(this);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure the `OnSerializing`/`OnSerialized` and `OnSerializing`/`OnError` will strictly be called by pair.

3. Is `SyncRoot` relate to or solve this problem?

Comment: How about when you use `Newtonsoft json`? If you want to use `SyncRoot`, what you describe seems to be similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728913/18789859), but I'm not sure if using `SyncRoot` to transfer in Signalr can achieve this effect.